# What are el and $el in backbone's view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, zepto

I'm trying to avoid wrapping with empty div when render view in backbone.
I do it with the following code

```
this.$el.replaceWith(this.template(this.model.attributes));
return this;
```

but I get empty div when I append this view by

```
$("#product-pannel").append(productsView.render().el);
```

someone give the solution like this

```
render: function(){
    var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    var newElement = $(html)
    this.$el.replaceWith(newElement);
    this.setElement(newElement);
    return this;
}
```

but I can't understand why should I do this so complicatedly above 
can someone tell me the mystery of `el` an `$el`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) points to the the view element (the one that holds rest of template) and [`$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) is a jQuery object represeting `el` element So that you don't have to do `$(this.el)` all the time.

This is clearly mentioned in the documentation.

You can either specify an existing DOM element as the view element using `el` option, or backbone creates a DOM element for every view. By default this will be a `<div>`. If you don't want an empty `<div>`, customize the element backbone creates as the top level element of your view template using options like `tagName`, [`attributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-attributes) etc.

[`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) is for dynamically changing the view element to something else... I've rarely (*or never*) seen it actually being used.